# How to handle Multiple select for file Upload

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to upload multiple files at single select button.selected files are not overwrite while more than one time select the files using the same button.Its Not like

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

by using this we can select multiple files at once, but i have to select multiple files multiple times by using the same button before Submitting the form.

Comment: you'll need to create your own control which handles that

Answer (score -1):

try this,
http://www.w3bees.com/2013/02/multiple-file-upload-with-php.html

this is a simple multi-upload script using php and html